# Can't make certain file associations

Tags: windows-10, sublime-text-3, regedit

I've been trying to associate .php files with Sublime Text 3 for the past few days, in Windows 10. I right click on the file, go to Properties, and under the General tab, I try to change the program which it opens with, which currently, is nothing. It doesn't change, and still shows, "Pick an app", next to, "Opens with:".

I tried to then associate it with Notepad too, in a similar manner, without any success. Suggestions from questions like [this](https://superuser.com/questions/655600/i-cant-set-a-program-as-the-default-to-open-a-filetype-with-in-windows-7) indicate some changes in the registry, which I have tried. I've rebooted my laptop after nearly every regedit, just in case. I've also checked if I could change or set file associations for other files, and I failed again, with .css. However, .mp4 and .bmp associations seem to be changeable, no issues (between VLC and Films & TV, and Photos and Photoshop, resp.).

Windows build is 1803. I only recently hard reset my laptop, so I'd like a solution which is a bit less drastic.

TIA

Comment: This seems to be a common problem: [How can I make Notepad++ the default program for .txt files?](https://superuser.com/q/1324367/150988) (answered), [Can’t use Notepad++ as default program for .txt](https://superuser.com/q/1367719/150988) (answered), [unable to associate .txt file with listed Visual Studio Code on Windows 10](https://superuser.com/q/1367659/150988) (answered) and [Unable to set default program for file types](https://superuser.com/q/1368778/150988) (not answered).

Comment: Update system through update feature at first. We also could configure default apps through Settings\Apps\Default apps\choose default apps by the file type.Try to switch with local admin account and check again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSMS wont give up file associations](https://superuser.com/questions/1373310/ssms-wont-give-up-file-associations)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following?

- In Windows *Explorer*, right-click on a *.php* file and select *Open with* (**not** *Properties*).
- You should see a dialog, `Windows can't open this type of file (.php)`.
- Click `Try an app on this PC`.
- Select the preferred application from the list, or browse to its location.
- **Click `always use this app to open .php files`** to make the association permanent (at least until the next Windows update destroys file associations).
- Click `OK`.

[image: Set file association]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have, and I have to keep doing it, every time I need to open the file. It just doesn't associate, after that.

Comment: If your not logging in as Administrator, try doing so to make the changes, then log back to a user account to see if they stick.